# Block inline script detecting devtools on edge/chromium

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, chromium, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am running the chromium version of edge, and have installed ublock origin, and I just wondering how I could disable this script from being loaded on a site. either through overrides or ublock origin preferably

```html
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
  if (-1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") || -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") || -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") || -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("coc_coc_browser")) {
    var checkStatus, element = new Image;
    Object.defineProperty(element, "id", {
      get: function() {
        throw checkStatus = "on", new Error("Dev tools checker")
      }
    }), setInterval(function() {
      checkStatus = "off", console.dir(element), "on" == checkStatus && (-1 != window.location.href.indexOf("?ep=")) && (window.location.href = window.location.href.split("watching.html")[0])
    }, 1e3)
  } - 1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") && window.addEventListener("devtoolschange", e => {
    1 == e.detail.isOpen && (-1 != window.location.href.indexOf("?ep=")) && (window.location.href = window.location.href.split("watching.html")[0])
  });
  ! function() {
    "use strict";
    const i = {
        isOpen: !1,
        orientation: void 0
      },
      e = (i, e) => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("devtoolschange", {
          detail: {
            isOpen: i,
            orientation: e
          }
        }))
      };
    setInterval(() => {
      const n = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth > 160,
        o = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight > 160,
        t = n ? "vertical" : "horizontal";
      o && n || !(window.Firebug && window.Firebug.chrome && window.Firebug.chrome.isInitialized || n || o) ? (i.isOpen && e(!1, void 0), i.isOpen = !1, i.orientation = void 0) : (i.isOpen && i.orientation === t || e(!0, t), i.isOpen = !0, i.orientation = t)
    }, 500), "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = i : window.devtools = i
  }();
  window.addEventListener("devtoolschange", e => {
    e.detail.isOpen && (-1 != window.location.href.indexOf("?ep=")) && (window.location.href = window.location.href.split("watching.html")[0])
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The code came compacted into 1 line, tided by stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If it is a separate js file, you can block specific js files to load. Open DevTools -> `network` tab -> select file and right click -> choose `block Request URL`.

But if it is loaded on the page, I think this will not be possible. If you choose to disable javascript, then all the script content of the page will not work, which will affect the overall operation of the page.

Answer (score 0):

uBO has some nice tools to stop these.
Have a look at https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/wiki/Resources-Library